# Search for installed apps/scopes

Tags: ubuntu-touch

How can I search/filter installed scopes/apps so that I can easily remove some stuff on Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this as well. For Apps you can go to the apps scope and long press an app icon. You'll go to the app description where you can uninstall.

For scopes though, I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

You can search the Ubuntu store for the scope and remove it from there. I didn't find a better way to do it so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using the command-line and you've shelled into your phone via adb (if adb is installed on your desktop/laptop this consists of enabling developer mode, connecting your phone to the desktop/laptop via usb, unlocking the screen and entering `adb shell` in a terminal) or installed the terminal app, you can list all installed apps and scopes with:

```
click list
```

You can uninstall apps and scopes with:

```
sudo click unregister <name_of_app_or_scope_as_generated_by_click_list> --user=phablet
```

If you change your mind, you can reinstall an app or scope (provided it was of the pre-installed ones, otherwise there's no guarantee that the corresponding files are still present on the device) using:

```
click register <name_of_app_...> current
```

(The "current" at the end means that you want to install the latest version (present on your device) of the app.)

Obviously, though, using the graphical interface is preferred.